# Neural Network MNIST

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I have been studying neural networks now for a while and made an implementation with python and numpy. I made a very simple example with XOR and it worked well. So I thought I go further and try the MNIST database.

There is my problem. I am using a NN with 784 inputs, 30 hidden and 10 output neuron.
The activation function of the hidden layer spits out only ones, so that the network basically stops learning. The math that I am doing is correct and the same implementation works well with the XOR example and I am reading the MNIST set properly. So I don't see, where the issue comes from.

```
import pickle
import gzip

import numpy as np

def load_data():
    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def transform_output(num):
    arr = np.zeros(10)
    arr[num] = 1.0
    return arr

def out2(arr):
    return arr.argmax()


data = load_data()
training_data = data[0]
training_input = np.array(training_data[0])
training_output = [transform_output(y) for y in training_data[1]]

batch_size = 10

batch_count = int(np.ceil(len(training_input) / batch_size))

input_batches = np.array_split(training_input, batch_count)
output_batches = np.array_split(training_output, batch_count)

#Sigmoid Function
def sigmoid (x):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-x))

#Derivative of Sigmoid Function
def derivatives_sigmoid(x):
    return x * (1.0 - x)

#Variable initialization
epoch=1 #Setting training iterations
lr=2.0 #Setting learning rate
inputlayer_neurons = len(training_input[0]) #number of features in data set
hiddenlayer_neurons = 30 #number of hidden layers neurons

output_neurons = len(training_output[0]) #number of neurons at output layer

#weight and bias initialization
wh=np.random.uniform(size=(inputlayer_neurons,hiddenlayer_neurons))
bh=np.random.uniform(size=(1,hiddenlayer_neurons))
wout=np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenlayer_neurons,output_neurons))
bout=np.random.uniform(size=(1,output_neurons))

for i in range(epoch):
    for batch in range(batch_count):

        X = input_batches[batch]
        y = output_batches[batch]

        zh1 = np.dot(X, wh)
        zh = zh1 + bh

        # data -> hidden neurons -> activations
        ah = sigmoid(zh)

        zo1 = np.dot(ah, wout)
        zo = zo1 + bout

        output = sigmoid(zo)

        # data -> output neurons -> error
        E = y - output

        print("debugging")
        print("X")
        print(X)
        print("WH")
        print(wh)
        print("zh1")
        print(zh1)
        print("bh")
        print(bh)
        print("zh")
        print(zh)
        print("ah")
        print(ah)
        print("wout")
        print(wout)
        print("zo1")
        print(zo1)
        print("bout")
        print(bout)
        print("zo")
        print(zo)
        print("out")
        print(output)
        print("y")
        print(y)
        print("error")
        print(E)
        # data -> output neurons -> slope
        slope_out = derivatives_sigmoid(output)

        # data -> output neurons -> change of error
        d_out = E * slope_out

        # data -> hidden neurons -> error = data -> output neurons -> change of error DOT output neurons -> output inputs (equal to hidden neurons) -> weights
        error_hidden = d_out.dot(wout.T)

        # data -> hidden neurons -> slope
        slope_h = derivatives_sigmoid(ah)

        # data -> hidden neurons -> change of error
        d_hidden = error_hidden * slope_h

        # hidden neurons -> output neurons -> weights = "" + hidden neurons -> data -> activations DOT data -> output neurons -> change of error
        wout = wout + ah.T.dot(d_out) * lr
        bout = bout + np.sum(d_out, axis=0, keepdims=True) * lr

        wh = wh + X.T.dot(d_hidden) * lr
        bh = bh + np.sum(d_hidden, axis=0, keepdims=True) * lr
    # testing results
    X = np.array(data[1][0][0:10])
    zh1 = np.dot(X, wh)
    zh = zh1 + bh

    # data -> hidden neurons -> activations
    ah = sigmoid(zh)

    zo1 = np.dot(ah, wout)
    zo = zo1 + bout

    output = sigmoid(zo)
    print([out2(y) for y in output])
    print(data[1][1][0:10])
```

so overall the output of the neural network is for every input the same and training it with different batch sizes, learning rates and 100 epochs did not help.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between XOR and MNIST problem is the number of classes: XOR is a binary classification and in MNIST there are 10 classes.

What you compute as an error `E` works for XOR, because sigmoid function can be used in binary case. When there are more than 2 classes, you have to use a [softmax function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), which is an extended version of sigmoid, and [cross entropy loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy). Take a look at [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier) to see the difference. You have correctly translated `y` to one-hot encoding, but `output` doesn't contain predicted probability distribution, in fact in contains a vector of 10 values, each very close to `1.0`. That's why the network doesn't learn.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have been using following tutorial http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html He uses a similar network as me, with plain 10 output neurons and sigmoid as me and gets around 95% success rate after first epoch. I will go through his code and mine and compare. The devil is in the detail. But yeah, as soon as I have this working, I will definitely go into softmax, dropout, and relus etc.

Comment: I'm actually a bit skeptical that described network can make 95% accuracy. His next example uses logistic regression (what I have suggested) and then convolutional neural network (which is much more likely to show such result), may be it was this model in action. But if you could prove me wrong and get to 90% accuracy, let me know, I'm curious to try this network myself.

Comment: I ran his code and I got 90% after first epoch repeatedly. The differences I have seen so far, is that he divides the learning rate depending on the batch size and randomizes the batches, which i did not. But this does not account for my issue. I get nothing, all neuron activations are all 1 in hidden and output layer

Comment: I updated the code. I had a couple of integer constants, that I made floats. Now I can see the weights updating, but the issue is still very similar.